# Bower init error

Tags: npm, bower

I have globally installed bower (`npm install -g bower`) and I am now trying to initialise my bower project.

But when I run:

`bower init`

Instead of seeing the prompt to enter the various fields for my project, I receive the error:

```
bower EINVALID      Name must be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes, "@" or spaces
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I realised the problem was my root folder had a `+` character in it, which bower doesn't like, apparently.

Simple problem, simple solution. Hope this saves someone else some time!

Comment: Yeah I had same problem. My project was containing `.com` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using NPM, and therefore have a package.json file, bower will try to use the name (and other fields: description, author, homepage) that you provided in that file.

when that name contains any of the disallowed characters, bower will throw you this error, as if you supplied an invalid name.

or if your filepath happens to contain any of the disallowed characters, you will also get this error